# Change NSTextField value from another viewcontroller swift

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift

so i was programming my app today when i ran in to this issue.
When i call a variable NSString "hello" from my second view controller, i can easily println it from my first view controller. but the problem is when i try to access the variable NSTextField i get error which either says nil, or other errors. how can i achieve this ?

Second View Controller :

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var txtDetail: NSTextField?
@IBOutlet weak var txtTitle: NSTextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}
}
```

First View Controller

```
let shared = ViewController()
class AddUrlViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBAction func readIt(sender: NSButton) {
        println(shared.txtTitle.stringValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: @DharmeshKheni i get this error in my debug log --> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: Yes --> println(shared.txtTitle.stringValue)

Comment: it asks me to delete the ? (error)

Comment: then remove ? and add this !

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not specific to swift. I haven't tackled learning much swift yet, but the answer applies to both Objective-C and swift.

The short answer: Don't. You should treat another view controller's views as private. This is an example of an important principle of OOD called encapsulation.

Instead, pass a string property to the other view controller. Then, in the other view controllers's viewWillAppear method (assuming it's a full-screen VC) copy the string into the field.

If the view might be on-screen when the string value is set, implement a custom setter and set the contents of the text field in the setter.